Artifact from build to be copied to Azure Storage
I'm running an MSBuild from a GitHub Actions workflow:
 jobs:

  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
          
      - name: Setup MSBuild path
        uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.0.2

      - name: Setup NuGet
        uses: NuGet/setup-nuget@v1.0.5

      - name: Restore nuget packages       
        run: nuget restore Winter50/Winter50.sln 
        env: 
          NuGetPackageSourceCredentials_BAC: Username=DUMMY_USER;Password=${{ secrets.PAT_NUGET }}

      - name: Build with MSBuild
        run: msbuild 'Winter50/Winter50.sln' /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU"
    
      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v1
        env:
          CREDENTIALS: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
        with:
          creds: ${{ env.CREDENTIALS }}
      
      - name: Copy file to Azure Storage 
        uses: azure/cli@v2
        with:
          azcliversion: latest
          inlineScript: |
            az account show
            echo "github.workspace - " ${{ github.workspace }}
            az storage file upload --account-name 'winterazure' --account-key ${{ secrets.AZURE_STORAGE_KEY }} --share-name 'winterazure' --path 'https://winterazure.file.core.windows.net/winterazure/drop/' --source "D:\a\Winter\Winter\Winter50\bin\Release\Winter50.dll"

I can see in the log file some dlls are created, in particular:
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
 copied to  "D:\a\Winter\Winter\Winter50\bin\Release\Winter50.dll.

The Build job runs as windows-latest. The azure/cli@v2 step when part of the Build fails for the following reason:
Run azure/cli@v2 Error: Error: Please use Linux-based OS as a runner'

I cant find any reason why cli@v2 wont run under windows-latest?

You didn't give your whole workflow. Are you running both steps in the same job?

No, so I guess that may be the problem. The build job runs as "Windows Latest". If the copy step is added to that job:
Run azure/cli@v2
env:
NUGET: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\nuget.exe\6.11.1\x64/nuget.exe
Error: Error: Please use Linux-based OS as a runner.
Warning: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\a_temp'

I've changed the copy step to be part of the build job and to show the new error message. I've added as much code as it allows in a question.

The azure cli actions requires it be run on a linux instance. However, you are building your file on a windows instance. Therefore you have to use two separate jobs. You need some way to transfer files between two jobs. This is where the standard upload-artifact and download-artfact actions come in.
In your build job, add the following step (after you have built the relevant files):
- uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
  with:
    name: my-artifact
    path: 'D:\a\Winter\Winter\Winter50\bin\Release\Winter50.dll'

To your azure-cli job add a the download-artifact step before you use any azure-cli steps that use it.
- uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
  with:
    name: my-artifact
- name: Display downloaded file
  run: ls -hal ./Winter50.dll

The uploaded artifact may contain multiple files, but it does not retain any information about the folders the files came from. So by default the files will be extracted into the root of the workspace for the job. Where the files are extracted can be configured by passing a path option to the download-artifact step.

This is exactly the correct answer. Thank you, much appreciated.
